# Coinciding values of Temperature scales

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature

In platinum resistance thermometers, the resistance varies slowly at lower temperatures and rapidly at high temperatures. Similarly, the expansion of mercury isn't uniform either. So the readings of mercury thermometers and platinum resistance thermometers need not coincide all the time. But why is it that they are forced to agree at the ice point and steam point?

Comment: Because that is what they are calibrated to.

Comment: Could you elaborate?